# Android Retrotfit modify fields of object after receive

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, gson

I need to modify some fields of object which I receive from server using Retrofit before I store it internally:
For example, server object model

```
{
    "field1":boolean;
    "field2":String
}
```

app object model:

```
{
    "field1":int=boolean?1:0;
    "field2":my prefix + String;
}
```

Should I write my own parser? Or will parsing using GSON would be enough with some interception before object is stored locally?

Comment: @shadox answer is correct. Use a JsonDeserializer to append any String or to make any operation before receiving your Model on the onResponse method.

Comment: Mark one of the answers please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not changing them after deserilization takes place? It's not that clear what you're trying to do but here is a solution.

(1) Write a deserilizer

```
public class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyModel> { 
    ...
}
```

(2) Register type adapter

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(MyModel.class, MyDeserializer)
    .create();
```

(3) Add it to retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(...)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build();
```

Alternatively you could just change your field's content after you get your instances.

Answer (score 1):

Using GSON you can write your own *JsonDeserializer*.
This example shows how translate int in JSON to boolean in your object.

```
public class BooleanTypeAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

@Override
public Boolean deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
        throws JsonParseException {
    int code = json.getAsInt();
    return code != 0;
}
}
```

And this:

```
new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(boolean.class, new BooleanTypeAdapter()).create();
```

Hope it helps.